# Github desktop showing a number at branch like #46

Tags: git, pull-request, cicd, github-desktop

Im seeing a number as shown below on my branch in GitHub desktop, here:

[image: Here]

I do understand that if your branch is behind the remote branch you would get down array here in this section with number of commits behind etc., like this:

[image: Like this]

But what might be this #46 on my branch? My branch is up to date with remote.

Comment: Do you have a ci/cd pipeline configured and that's commit is from the 46th run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Github when you find the `#` (hash), it indicates a unique reference to an issue, or a Pull Request.**

If you search on remote repo the issue/pull-request number `46` probably you find the answer to your question.

In this case from the symbol of the image reported the `#46` is a Pull Request and the "RED X" means that some workflow is failed.

For more detail you can visit this [page](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls).